# SignalR Core not generating(mapping) Client methods

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

The SignalR Core is generating Hub proxies script, but not adding the "client" methods. *(No errors in server or client - only not working)*

Generated JS from `<script src="http://localhost/signalr/hubs">`

```
proxies['messageHub'] = this.createHubProxy('messageHub'); 
proxies['messageHub'].client = { };
proxies['messageHub'].server = {
        handleMessage: function (receivedString) {
            return proxies['messageHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['messageHub'], $.merge(["HandleMessage"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
         }
    };
```

Here's the Hub in Server Side:

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public void HandleMessage(string receivedString)
    {
        var responseString = string.Empty;

        MessageHandler.HandleMessage(receivedString, ref responseString);

        Clients.All.sendMessage(responseString);

    }
}
```

The **sendMessage** methos should be included in the messageHub client proxies in the JS file.
    *$.connection.messageHub.client.sendMessage is undefined*

Only the **handleMessage** for server proxies was created (and working).

Here's my StartUp.cs inclusions for SignalR:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RoleFilterAttribute());
        }).AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new DefaultContractResolver());
services.AddSignalR(options => options.Hubs.EnableDetailedErrors = true)
```

Configure:

```
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseSignalR();
```

project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server": "0.2.0-*",
```

**SOME ADDITIONAL TENTATIVES:**

1 - Change method case in Server Side to see if it's mapped:

```
Clients.All.SendMessage(responseString);
```

Did not work!

2 - Change the client side to dynamic mapping:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost/');
var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('messageHub');
connection.start({ withCredentials: false }).done(function () { console.log("CONNECTED") });
proxy.on("sendMessage", function (result) {console.log(result);});
proxy.invoke("handleMessage", msg).done(function(result)console.log(result);});
```

Again only the handleMessage (server) worked.

Comment: I would suggest to follow the instructions provided in [Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr)

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the docs you are missing method name so the send all line should look like this

```
public void HandleMessage(string receivedString)
{
    var responseString = string.Empty;

    MessageHandler.HandleMessage(receivedString, ref responseString);

    Clients.All.SendMessage("SendMessage",responseString);

}
```

Also in the following is the correct way

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.Hub<MessageHub>("/messageHub");
        });
```

and finally

```
    var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost/');
var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('messageHub');
connection.start({ withCredentials: false }).done(function () { console.log("CONNECTED") });
proxy.on("SendMessage", function (result) {console.log(result);});
proxy.invoke("HandleMessage", msg).done(function(result)console.log(result);});
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core SignalR doesn't generate client proxies. There's good advice in the comment to follow the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio